# Apache Airflow - How to retrieve dag_run data outside an operator in a flow triggered with TriggerDagRunOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I set up two DAGs, let's call the first one orchestrator and the second one worker. Orchestrator work is to retrieve a list from an API and, for each element in this list, trigger the worker DAG with some parameters.

The reason why I separated the two workflows is I want to be able to replay only the "worker" workflows that fail (if one fails, I don't want to replay all the worker instances).

I was able to make things work but now I see how hard it is to monitor, as my task_id are the same for all, so I decided to have dynamic task_id based on a value retrieved from the API by "orchestrator" workflow.

However, I am not able to retrieve the value from the dag_run object outside an operator. Basically, I would like this to work :

```
with models.DAG('specific_workflow', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    name = context['dag_run'].name
    hello_world = BashOperator(task_id='hello_{}'.format(name), bash_command="echo Hello {{ dag_run.conf.name }}", dag=dag)
    bye = BashOperator(task_id='bye_{}'.format(name), bash_command="echo Goodbye {{ dag_run.conf.name }}", dag=dag)

    hello_world >> bye
```

But I am not able to define this "context" object. However, I am able to access it from an operator (PythonOperator and BashOperator for instance).

Is it possible to retrieve the dag_run object outside an operator ?

Comment: In the code quote, I defined an hypothetic "context" object from which I can retrieve the "dag_run" object. But it is only an hypothesis and I don't know if such object exists.

Comment: To rephrase, I would like to retrieve a dag_run object outside an operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's easily possible currently. For example, as part of the worker run process, the DAG is retrieved without any TaskInstance context provided besides where to find the DAG: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/f18e2550543e455c9701af0995bc393ee6a97b47/airflow/bin/cli.py#L353

The context is injected later: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/c5f1c6a31b20bbb80b4020b753e88cc283aaf197/airflow/models.py#L1479

The `run_id` of the DAG would be good place to store this information.

Answer (score 2):

Yup it is possible
What I tried and worked for me is

> In the following code block, I am trying to show all possible ways to use the configurations passed,
> directly to different operators

```
pyspark_task = DataprocSubmitJobOperator(
    task_id="task_0001",
    job=PYSPARK_JOB,
    location=f"{{{{dag_run.conf.get('dataproc_region','{config_data['cluster_location']}')}}}}",
    project_id="{{dag_run.conf['dataproc_project_id']}}",
    gcp_conn_id="{{dag_run.conf.gcp_conn_id}}"
)
```

So either you can use it like

```
"{{dag_run.conf.field_name}}" or "{{dag_run.conf['field_name']}}"
```

Or
If you want to use some default values in case the configuration field is optional,

```
f"{{{{dag_run.conf.get('field_name', '{local_variable['field_name_0002']}')}}}}"
```